# Android - Open email intent with attachment prompt

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

Been trying to figure this out and can't seem to find any clues on how to make it happen.

I'm trying to launch an e-mail intent to send an e-mail but have it also automatically open the attachment prompt so the user can select images to attach to the email.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Currently I'm using the standard way of sending email, seen below:

```
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"test@email.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test");

        try {
            startActivity(emailIntent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No e-mail client found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any help.

EDIT:

If this is not possible then is there a way to stream the images taken by the camera (multiple) and add them as an attachment to the intent? Could not seem to find a way to do this with multiple images, only one, which is how I had the app setup before the requirement came to take multiple at a time and e-mail them.

EDIT 2:

Used this method to take multiple photos after coming into onActivityResult from a camera intent.

```
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            uriList.add(Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

            try {

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                photoFile = CreateImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                resultCode = 9999;
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }           
    }
```

Comment: That's not going to be possible by any documented and supported means. There's no requirement for a third-party email app to support attachments at all.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply. I edited my original question since this does not seem possible.

Comment: Use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` N times to take N pictures, then try `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` to attach them. I am not sure how many email apps will support `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, though.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up trying a few things and got an implementation working for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
String Message="<b>Name :</b> "+ed_name.getText().toString()+"<br><br>"+
               "<b>Email : </b>"+ed_email.getText().toString()+"<br><br>"+
               "<b>Mobile Number : </b>"+ed_mobile.getText().toString()+"<br><br>"+
               "<b>City : </b>"+ed_city.getText().toString()+"<br><br>"+
               "<b>Subject : </b>"+ed_subject.getText().toString()+"<br><br>"+
               "<b>Inquiry : </b>"+ed_msg.getText().toString()+"<br><br>";

            Spanned FinalMessage=Html.fromHtml(Message);


            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"test@gmail.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Inquiry By : "+ed_name.getText().toString());
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,FinalMessage);
            //emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[] {GlobleVaribles.EmailBCC });
            //emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[] {GlobleVaribles.EmailCC });
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Pick an Email provider"));
```